# How to combine multiple images fast for page views counter

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, counter

How can I combine multiple images, such as base image with logo and number of digits images to display graphical counter with pageviews count, updated dynamically?

It should be very fast, with thousands of renders per second. User should see counter image without Javascript and with single `img` tag.

I prefer to implement that counter with Python using PIL library, but other solutions welcome as well.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention the intended size of each digit, in pixels and with a bit-count, to make it easier to estimate the processing power required.

Comment: It should look like that:
http://top.mail.ru/i/counters/to_face_new.gif

Comment: Without hand cursor, of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precompute for the given background the image of a single digit (for each digit 0 ... 10) at each digit position.
Then to create arbitrary number you only have to paste the correct images next to eachother, but you won't have to do any alpha blending. Therefore this must be more efficient.

Also, if certain page counts are more common (e.g. page counts < 10000) you might want to precompute these (10000) complete counter images to serve those directly.

**EDIT:**
You can do this with python PIL, or any other method. If you have a specific difficulty with PIL then please ask a more direct question about the problems you have encounterd.

Comment: By the way, I though that in pageview count images only last two or three digits change frequently, so I can minimize combining operations to only two or even one if I`ll precompute a few base images for logo and first digits.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think that you should evaluate where, under your work load, you can gain most time by precomputing numbers. You might precompute a lot of images this way.

Comment: Rather than precomputing, compute as needed, but cache intermediate images.  So you might have a counter that says "12345 page views", but you'll also have a set of images to build on that say "123__ page views", and one that says "1____ page views", and finally a "_____ page views".  When you pass 12399, create a new 124__, and 12400.  After 19999, create a new 2____, 200__, and 20000.  (Whether you do per-hundred or per-ten is up to you).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to handle thousands "renders" per second I would not suggest to generate the images on the fly. How about precomputing n images where n is the expected (you might want to be generous here) count you have to handle?

I know you state that you don't want to use javascript and you only want one `img` tag, but I would recommend to reconsider pushing visualization to the client side as you would burn unnecessary resources if you really get the load you are expecting (thousands hits / second, every hit incrementing the counter and generating an image using PIL).

Answer (score 0):

Since the background is uniform in your example, render the string "0123456789" and use [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/) to build the counter.

Comment: That counter would be pasted to other people pages. Something like Google Analytics, but with counter.